# How to insert "footline"-style page number into "headline"

Tags: beamer, sectioning, page-numbering

When inserting page numbers into beamer slides, I usually use:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

Is it possible to do this for headline, something like:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[page number]
```

Comment: Have you tried `\insertframenumber`?

Comment: It seems that `\insertframenumber` only shows the current page number, but I also want the total page number (excluding appendix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's not installed by default, but you do something like this:

```
\defbeamertemplate{headline}{page number}{%
    \vskip1pt%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]%
    \usebeamertemplate{footline}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[page number]
```

Since the footline template is set inside the group it's not affected by your global theme.  You can have a regular footline that's something else like `infolines`--although I assume you don't want that one because it's already got the page number in it.

This does seem to clobber the headline in some of the fancier themes.  So you might try instead `\addtobeamertemplate`:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \vskip1pt%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]%
    \setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{use=headline,fg=headline.fg,bg=headline.bg}
    \usebeamertemplate{footline}%    
}{% don't add anything after
}
```

Comment: Both methods work perfectly:) Thank you very much!  Strangely, the colours of the page numbers in these two methods are different (grey vs. dark)

Comment: @user2015: Notice that in the second example I played around with the color by setting the beamer-color `page number in head/foot` to be the same as that of `headline`

Comment: I see:) The second method is much more flexible then. Thank you very much!